# Как проверить значение input по кнопке?React-native

Tags: input, button, react-native

Прошу помочь мне в создавшейся проблеме,только начал изучать React-native,и столкнулся с таким вопросом,как я могу с помощью кнопки,проверять значение введенного текста в поле TextInput?
Хочу получить по нажатию кнопки значение погоды,то есть проверяется имя города который введен в TextInput,и в компоненте Weather_info отображаются все данные касательно города.
Если к тэгу TextInput применить атрибут onChangeText,то вся конструкция работает,но с моментальной проверкой,что не очень удобно.
Вот пример(за основу взял видео с youtube),и немного переделываю под себя. Прошу строго не судить,но c данной проблемой уже приличное время вожусь.

```
//Component App
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Form from './components/Form'
import Weather_info from './components/Weather_info'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state  = {
            temp:undefined,
            city:undefined,
            country:undefined,
            sunrise:undefined,
            sunset:undefined,
            error:undefined
        }
    }

get_weather = async (name_city) =>{

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name_city}&appid=e48c8198cd1232bda9322dcb95242025&units=metric`)

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({
        temp:data.main.temp,
        city:data.name,
        country:data.sys.country,
        sunrise:data.sys.sunrise,
        sunset:data.sys.sunset,
        error:""
    })

}
    render(){
        return(

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Form weather_data = {this.get_weather}/>
                <Weather_info {...this.state}/>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;

//Component Form

import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';


class Form extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View  style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                 type="text" 
                 name={"city"} 
                 onSubmitEditing={(name_city)=>this.props.weather_data(name_city)} 
                 placeholder={"Город"}/>
                 <Button title="Получить погоду"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
export default Form;


//Component Weather_info

import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


class Weather_info extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                { this.props.city &&
                <View>
                    <Text>Местоположение:{this.props.city},{this.props.country}</Text>
                    <Text> Температура: {this.props.temp}</Text>
                    <Text> Восход солнца:{this.props.sunrise}</Text>
                    <Text> Закат: {this.props.sunset}</Text>
                </View>
                }
            </View>

        )
    }
}

export default Weather_info;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать работать через state, и с помощью onPress на кнопке передавать данные из стейта

```
class Form extends Component {
    state = {
       city: ''
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <View  style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                 type="text" 
                 name={"city"} 
                 onChangeText={city => this.setState({city})}
                 value={this.state.city} 
                 placeholder={"Город"}/>
                 <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.weather_data(this.state.city)} 
                    title="Получить погоду"
                 />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо,Вы решили мою проблему.
Теперь буду разбираться дальше.
Вы крутой:)!